# continuous function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $P$ a metric space and $f: P \times [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ a continuous function. Show that the average value function $\mu: P \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ given by

$$\mu(\alpha)=\frac{\int_{a}^b f  \left( \alpha , x \right)dx}{b-a}$$
It is a continuous function

Comment: In essence you have to show the integral of a continuous function is continuous.

Comment: Also, compactness of $[a,b]$ plays an important role.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this is somewhat trickier than the other comments and answers would seem to suggest. In fact at first I didn't see why it was *true*, unless we assume that $P$ is locally compact or something.

Hint: Since $P$ is a metric space, it's enough to show that $\mu(\alpha_n)\to\mu(\alpha)$ if $(\alpha_n)$ is a sequence in $P$ with $\alpha_n\to\alpha$.

So suppose that $\alpha_n\to\alpha$. Let $A=\{\alpha\}\cup\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots\}$. Show that $A$ is compact. Hence $A\times[a,b]$ is compact, and so $f$ is *uniformly* continuous on $A\times[a,b]$. Now we're done because...

Comment: P is not locally compact

Comment: @JhoanLaldrup Read what I wrote a little more carefully - "_at first_ I didn't see...". I gave a proof that's valid for any metric space.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Notice that since the integral is linear, and the function $f$ is continuous, we have 
$$ \mu(\alpha) - \mu(\beta) = \frac{\int [f(\alpha,x)-f(\beta,x) ]dx}{b-a} $$
Try to fill in the rest